# Not able to migrate new table in laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I've created a table using command

create table: **php artisan make:migration create_movie --create=movie**

then added body & user_id columns to code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('movie', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->text('body');

        $table->integer('user_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('movie');
}
```

then hit **php artisan migrate** command

but this is showing me this exception and I'm not able to add movie table to the database

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
  `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim
  estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: The problem maybe is not in this migration ? Seems like you tray adds users twice.

Maybe tray run  "composer dumpautoload"

Comment: Maybe you dropped or truncate your `migrations` table? It seems the problem is when trying to create (or re-create) `users` table, not this `movie` table.

Comment: Seems like `users` table is not added with artisan command but still exists. If you don't care of data in tables (careful, this would delete all tables) try with `php artisan migrate:fresh` or  `php artisan migrate:refresh` commands. Or you can delete tables manually than issue  `php artisan migrate` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try run new generate movie specific file migration like this

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/{{Your_movie_migration_filename}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please empty migrations table and run `php artisan migrate` command

**OR**

Create test folder in migrations folder then newly created migration moved/copied in test folder and run below command in your terminal/cmd like:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty database tables and run migration again or if you do not want to lose your data do the follow:

Find your movie table migration (Database>Migrations) and change the date to any oldest date on the migration file so that it goes first in the folder.

Run migration again, even if you get error about users table (its not error, its just saying that it already exist) the movie table will be created.

> Migration migrates from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next **artisan** command that will **roll back all of your migrations** and then execute the **migrate command**. Please, check de documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#roll-back-migrate-using-a-single-command

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```